# Copying files from Sharepoint to Azure Data lake gen 2 using Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-data-factory, sharepoint-online, azure-synapse

I am trying to copy files from Sharepoint to Azure data lake gen2 using Azure Synapse pipeline

I have set up the prerequisites and configured the pipeline as mentioned in the document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory#copy-file-from-sharepoint-online)

Web succeeds and passes a token to the Copy Data activity. However, I am getting the error in the sink side

[image]

Getting below error message

[image]

Not sure what is the issue? can anyone advise? I referred various posts but no success

Comment: Is IRM enabled on Sharepoint Online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error – The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

This error occurs because of authentication issue.

> This operation requires SharePoint Online site owner permission. You
> can find the owner by going to the site home page -> click the "X
> members" in the right corner -> check who has the "Owner" role.

Also check

> Even if an Azure AD application has FullControl permissions on
> SharePoint Online, you can't copy files from document libraries with
> IRM enabled.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/381621/copy-data-from-sharepoint-using-adf-1.html

Answer (score 0):

A few weeks ago I ran into the same problem following the same documentation.

I was able to solve the problem by enabling Custom App Authentication. For SPO tenants that were created after 07.11.2018 the authentication via ACS app-only access token is disabled by default (see blue box in link below).

[Granting access using SharePoint App-Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs)

I decided to write a blog post with a step by step guide on how to move multiple files from an SPO folder to Blob Storage using Azure Data Factory, maybe you will find it usefull:

[Copy files from SharePoint to Blob Storage](https://www.syntera.ch/blog/2022/10/10/copy-files-from-sharepoint-to-blob-storage-using-azure-data-factory/)